# Examples of noncommutative Bezout domains

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, big-list, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings

I would like to see some (or many!) examples of noncommutative Bezout domains (one-sided principal ideals sum to one-sided principal ideals). I've read somewhere that it's not easy to find an example of a right but not left Bezout domain, but even though I would be glad to see it, I'm actually more interested in examples of domains that are Bezout on both sides. (And of course aren't PIDs.) A Google search gave me nothing, as did a search on this site.

Comment: Made CW at OP's suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

See the paper:

*P. M. Cohn*, MR 153696 [**Rings with a weak algorithm**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=153696), *Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* **109** (1963), 332--356.See the paper "Rings with a weak algorithm" by P. M. Cohn.

Comment: I just edited your answer to include a more full citation. However, you might also consider including a summary as to why this paper is relevant. For example, what is a specific example in this paper which helps answer the question.